# Identify Apex Classes used by what LWC/AURA components

Tags: lightning-web-components

Any thoughts on how I could replicate the below for identifying what components are using what Apex classes, eg this is for AURA components

```java
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Map<String, String> getComponentControllerMap() {
        Map<String, String> componentControllers = new Map<String, String>();

        Pattern controllerPattern = Pattern.compile('controller="(.*?)"');
        // Find all the components and the controller they have defined
        for (AuraDefinition ad : [
            SELECT
                AuraDefinitionBundle.DeveloperName,
                DefType,
                Source
            FROM AuraDefinition
            WHERE DefType = 'COMPONENT'
            AND AuraDefinitionBundle.NamespacePrefix = ''
            ORDER BY AuraDefinitionBundle.DeveloperName
        ]) {
            if (ad.Source.containsIgnoreCase('controller=')) {
                Matcher matcher = controllerPattern.matcher(ad.Source);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    String className = matcher.group(1);
                    componentControllers.put(ad.AuraDefinitionBundle.DeveloperName, className);
                }
            }
        }

        return componentControllers;
    }
```

I do suspect it is not possible, but if I don't ask...

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/124555/find-out-dependent-fields-object-and-classes-in-salesforce and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.222.0.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm might be of interest?

Comment: Thanks @KrisGoncalves, but it does not get me the ApexClasses used
This query shows me WHERE the LWC components are used
```
SELECT RefMetadataComponentName, MetadataComponentName, MetadataComponentType FROM MetadataComponentDependency WHERE RefMetadataComponentType = 'LightningComponentBundle'
```
Whilst this query shows the LWC Component dependencies
```
SELECT RefMetadataComponentName, RefMetadataComponentType, MetadataComponentName, MetadataComponentType FROM MetadataComponentDependency WHERE MetadataComponentType = 'LightningComponentBundle'
```
Which shows 0 results

Comment: @KrisGoncalves this works for AURA
```SQL
SELECT RefMetadataComponentName, RefMetadataComponentType, MetadataComponentName, MetadataComponentType FROM MetadataComponentDependency WHERE MetadataComponentType = 'AuraDefinition' AND RefMetadataComponentType = 'ApexClass'
```